# Value Text issue with Stacked Bar Chart - AChartEngine

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

Hello all Android developers,

I have used AChartEngine to draw a Stacked Bar Chart ( with type = HEAP ) and I get the problem when display the value text in a chart ( please view the picture on the below ).

Could you please to fix this issue?

[image: The issue chart]

The expect chart I want.

[image: The expect chart]

Comment: lolz. where is your code?

Comment: Sorry, I used this library https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout .

All I have done is implementing their code, but it seems like the library itself does not support the expected chart so I want to config it but I couldn't.

Comment: Probably a bug. Post it here: http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/list

Comment: i have worked on it and i think its not doable 
any way if you found any solution please share it :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I decided to use stacked chart instead of heap chart. In the library's source code, they write the number on top of a bar (like margin each bar's top xx pixels). This way when we zoom or click, the positions go wrong.

What I did is digging into their code, change how to write the number from their way to my way: start positioning from the x line, not from top of the bar.